# python eventlet - file async(non-blocking) io

Tags: python, eventlet

According to [eventlet document](http://eventlet.net/) :

```
It uses epoll or libevent for highly scalable non-blocking I/O.
```

I know non-blocking I/O here covers the case when you interact with sockets. After the socket gets greened/patched by eventlet, the socket connection becomes non-blocking.

My questions is: Does this non-blocking I/O here covers file I/O as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That would either

- **True async IO with callbacks**: impose unexpected restrictions; good on Windows and FreeBSD though
- **Non-blocking IO**: disable filesystem cache (at least on Linux and FreeBSD) and still not guarantee that file IO would not block (at least on Linux on commonly used file systems)
- **Thread pool**: incur unexpected performance and memory costs

Thread pool is the easiest, most portable and most predictable way though. You could easily wrap your calls with `eventlet.tpool.execute`.

Comment: That's what I found out as well, like socket connection, eventlet can make it green/async no problems. But file I/O, unless using it in tpool, Greenpool just has no way make it async. So it doesn't make sense to do file I/O in green thread, correct? Because it can easily cooperatively block everything else in the same process.

Comment: Yes and no. Each `open` or other file operation really does block all green threads. But the time it blocks for is usually quite small. On the other hand, if you are deploying on some massively shared hosting, like Amazon EC2 with possible disk IO starvation, yes, it may block for long time and then `tpool` would be very useful. Measuring everything is the key to success.